# Alert for Old Access Keys in AWS

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-sns

I didn't get an answer to my original question, but I've tweaked my code and I'm leaving this here in case anyone is trying to figure this out in the future. I'm new to Python, but this worked. This is a Python script I created for a Lambda function that checks the users in your AWS account and publishes a notification to an SNS topic. I've scheduled a CloudWatch rule with a cron expression to run it every day.

```
import boto3, json, time, datetime, sys, re
iam_client = boto3.client('iam')
sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
users = iam_client.list_users()
user_list = []
for key in users['Users']:
    user_list = key['UserName']
    accesskeys = iam_client.list_access_keys(UserName=key['UserName'])
    for items in user_list.split('\n'):
        for key in accesskeys['AccessKeyMetadata']:
            accesskeydate = accesskeys['AccessKeyMetadata'][0]['CreateDate']
            accesskeydate = accesskeydate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            currentdate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
            accesskeyd = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(accesskeydate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
            currentd = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(currentdate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
            active_days = (currentd - accesskeyd)/60/60/24
            message = (key['UserName'],int(round(active_days))),
            message = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', "", str(message))
            message = re.sub(r' ', ' is ', str(message))
            if active_days >= 90:
                sns_client.publish(
                    TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:topic-name',
                    Subject='User with Old Access Key Detected',
                    Message="The access key for " + str(message) + " days old. This user access key should be replaced ASAP.",
                )
```

Comment: So you want the list sent in one message, instead of one message for each old key?

Comment: Yes, that's correct